# Adding a dependency to pom.xml causes jetty to fail

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml, gdata

I have a project where I need to use google's gdata library. When I add it's dependency to the pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
 <artifactId>core</artifactId>
 <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My project fails to run in maven-build jetty:run.
The resulting error is:

```
 2013-11-02 00:47:33.025::WARN:  failed default
2013-11-02 00:47:33.025::WARN:  failed ContextHandler@76c64124{/myappname-app,file:/src/main/webapp/}
2013-11-02 00:47:33.026::WARN:  failed ContextHandlerCollection@51dedf67
2013-11-02 00:47:33.026::WARN:  failed HandlerCollection@7f1d0d2e
2013-11-02 00:47:33.035::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8091
2013-11-02 00:47:33.035::WARN:  failed Server@41c65037
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
```

and after the failure message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.0.0:run (default-cli) on project projectname-impl: Failure: org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler$Context cannot be cast to org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler$SContext -> [Help 1]
```

however if I remove the dependency, the project runs fine again.

( I do need to use the dependency )

How can I fix this?

Comment: Upgrade jetty and the maven-jetty-plugin.  Seriously.  Version 6.0.0 is [over 150 versions behind](https://gist.github.com/joakime/642ba1dbe2563fabfcd8#file-jetty-versions-txt-L1-L191). (Not kidding!)

Comment: That is exactly the solution. Gdata includes an old Jetty, excluding the old Jetty in the pom solved it.